# C++ Identifier Not Found error

Tags: c++

I get identifer not found error for "startProcess":

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    bool result=startProcess(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}

bool  startProcess(int argc, char* argv[])
{


}
```

But why?

Comment: Declare it before you use it.

Answer (score 3):

Functions need to be at least declared before you use them, if not defined. Try putting this at the top of your file.

```
bool startProcess(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

The above is a *declaration*, you're telling the compiler that at some point, you're going to provide a *definition* for the function, which is this:

```
bool  startProcess(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   code here...    
}
```

This difference between a *declaration* and a *definition* is important for being able to separate your code into separate files. If you had placed your *definition* of `startProcess` in a different file, the compiler would never actually see it while compiling the file that contains `main`. However, with the *declaration*, you're making a promise that it exists somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't declared that function before `main()`, so the compiler is unaware of the existence of `startProcess` at the point of call:

```
bool startProcess(int argc, char* argv[]); // <== Informs the compiler about
                                           //     the existence of startProcess
                                           //     (and about its signature)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool result = startProcess(argc, argv); // OK because of the declaration
                                            // above: the compiler knows that
                                            // somewhere (possibly in another
                                            // translation unit) the definition
                                            // of startProcess is provided
    return 0;
}

bool startProcess(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the definition directly before `main()`:

```
bool  startProcess(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool result = startProcess(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! I completely forgot about that. Been coding in C# for too long. THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should put the declaration of `startProcess` before main if you would like to put definition of it after `main`.

```
bool  startProcess(int argc, char* argv[]); //declare here

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool result=startProcess(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}

bool  startProcess(int argc, char* argv[])
{
}
```

or you can put the definition of `startProcess` directly before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a prototype before your main function.

```
bool startProcess(int argc, char* argv[]);
```